# Make a list separated by commas into multiple columns / readable form

Tags: tables, multicol, layout

I've got a list of numbers I generated using an algorithm and saved in comma-separated format. For example, `1,2,3,4,5,6,...,100`. The list is quite long and simply pasting it into my document is not reader-friendly. I'd like to reformat it into, for example, several columns, or some way to make this long list of numbers easier to read. I can't regenerate my numbers as the algorithm takes a while to run. How can I make latex present my comma-separated list in multiple neat columns (e.g. multicolumn environment), for example?

Comment: What is the biggest number you have in the list?

Comment: it's hard to answer as you show no code. Do you have the list as a simple macro `\def\foo{1,2,3}` and if so does it have spaces after the commas? without spaces the list won't linebreak so it will be an overfull line, with spaces it will linebreak. If it is a macro you could iterate over the list and make a tabular inserting `&` and `\\ ` as needed. However if you don't have an actual command with the list but rather a commadn that generates th elist you would have to modify the generator to insert `&` while generating the output and the details will depend on how you are constructing the list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I am not very experienced with latex and I don't know what a macro is, I am mainly just writing into my document and using \begin{table} and \begin{equation} when necessary etc

Comment: @yannisl No bigger than 8 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defines a command that accepts a comma list of numbers (or anything) and sets each in a box of the width specified in the second argument, so you get automatic tabular layout with as many columsn as fit in the current width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mylist}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\tablelist{mm}{
  \begin{flushleft}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn #1 {\makebox[#2][r]{##1}\linebreak[0]}
  \end{flushleft}
  }
  
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\tablelist\mylist{2cm}

\bigskip

\tablelist\mylist{1cm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `readarray` package concepts, I read the `mydata.csv` file data into a `\def` named `\myfiledata`.  Then I parse `\myfiledata` into a 2-D array `\mydata` of width 5.  Finally, I typeset the array into a `tabular` format.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.csv}
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
18,19,20,21,...,100
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readdef{mydata.csv}\myfiledata
\readarraysepchar{,}
\edef\myfiledata{\myfiledata,,,,,}% ADD A COMMA FOR EACH COLUMN
\readarray\myfiledata\mydata[-,5]% 5 DENOTES DESIRED COLUMNS
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{r}}
\typesetarray\mydata
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an alternative formatting, if one desires to use the complete `linewidth`.  Only specification required is the width of each entry, specified here as `5ex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.csv}
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
18,19,20,21,...,100
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readdef{mydata.csv}\myfiledata
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readarray\myfiledata\mydata[-,1]
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\typesetcell[1]{\makebox[5ex][r]{#1\unskip}\allowbreak}
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{}
\typesetarray\mydata
\end{document}
```

[image]